# Combine two stream in Streambuilder and return a single ListView (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I'm trying to combine two streams from two different collections (the first is 'avvenimenti' and the second is 'prospettive' ) into a single StreamBuilder that return one ListView.

I have tried many options (using Rx, StreamBuilder that return a StremBuilder that return a ListView etc ..) but failed to adapt them to my project.

On children property of ListView i can add only one List:

```
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Global.avvenimentiRef.streamData(),
      builder: (context, snap1) {
        if (snap1.hasData) {
          List<Avvenimento> avvenimenti = snap1.data;
          return StreamBuilder(
            stream: Global.prospettiveRef.streamData(),
            builder: (context, snap2) {
              if (snap2.hasData) {
                List<Prospettive> prospettive = snap2.data;
                return Scaffold(
                  //this is the single ListView i want to use
                  body: ListView(
                    primary: false,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
                    children: 
                    prospettive.map((prospettiveId) => ProspettiveItem(prospettiveId: prospettiveId)).toList(),
                    avvenimenti
                        .map((avvenimentoId) =>
                            AvvenimentoItem(avvenimentoId: avvenimentoId))
                        .toList(),
                  
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return LoadingScreen();
              }
            },
          );
        } else {
          return LoadingScreen();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

my db:

```
lass Document<T> {
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final String path;
  DocumentReference ref;

  Document({this.path}) {
    ref = _db.doc(path);
  }

  Future<T> getData() {
    return ref.get().then((v) => Global.models[T](v.data()) as T);
  }

  Stream<T> streamData() {
    return ref.snapshots().map((v) => Global.models[T](v.data()) as T);
  }

  Future<void> upsert(Map data) {
    return ref.set(Map<String, dynamic>.from(data));
  }
}

class Collection<T> {
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final String path;
  CollectionReference ref;

  Collection({this.path}) {
    ref = _db.collection(path);
  }

  Future<List<T>> getData() async {
    var snapshot = await ref.get();
    return snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => Global.models[T](doc.data()) as T)
        .toList();
  }

  Stream<List<T>> streamData() {
    return ref.snapshots().map((list) =>
        list.docs.map((doc) => Global.models[T](doc.data()) as T).toList());
  }
}
```

models:

```
class ElencoProspettive {
  String fonte;
  String title;
  
  ElencoProspettive({this.fonte, this.title});

  ElencoProspettive.fromMap(Map data) {
    fonte = data['data'] ?? '';
    title = data['title'] ?? '';
  }
}

class Prospettive {
  String id;
  String titlePro;
  List<ElencoProspettive> elenco;

  Prospettive({this.id, this.titlePro, this.elenco});

  factory Prospettive.fromMap(Map data) {
    return Prospettive(
        id: data['data'] ?? '',
        titlePro: data['title'] ?? '',
        elenco: (data['elenco'] as List ?? [])
            .map((v) => ElencoProspettive.fromMap(v))
            .toList());
  }
}
```

models:

```
class Global {
  //
  // App Data
  //
  static final String title = 'Annales';

  static final FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();

  static final Map models = {
    Avvenimento: (data) => Avvenimento.fromMap(data),
    Prospettive: (data) => Prospettive.fromMap(data),
  };

  static final Collection<Avvenimento> avvenimentiRef =
      Collection<Avvenimento>(path: 'avvenimenti');

  static final Collection<Prospettive> prospettiveRef =
      Collection<Prospettive>(path: 'propsettive');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CombineLatestStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html) from `Rx` since you mentioned that you already tried it.

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: CombineLatestStream.list([
        Global.avvenimentiRef.streamData(),
        Global.prospettiveRef.streamData(),
      ]),
      builder: (context, snap1)
```

- Notice that You `StreamBuilder` will reloaded if one of the streams changed
- You can access the data returned by the stream using `snap1.data[0]` or `snap1.data[1]` ..ect

for the list, you can try

```
ListView(
                    primary: false,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
                    children: 
                    [...(prospettive.map((prospettiveId) => ProspettiveItem(prospettiveId: prospettiveId)).toList()),
                    ...(avvenimenti
                        .map((avvenimentoId) =>
                            AvvenimentoItem(avvenimentoId: avvenimentoId))
                        .toList())],
                  
                  ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I always find myself at the same point. That is: ListView children: accept 1 argument but I need both avvenimenti and prospettive

Comment: Happy to help! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna install a package and don't wanna nest your `StreamBuilder`s, you can try this Dart vanilla solution: I made this by ticking a single stream controller when any of the provided streams tick something:

```dart
/// Merge all [streams] events into a single [Stream] that emits void
/// when any of the [streams] emits an event.
Stream<void> combineStreams(List<Stream<dynamic>> streams) {
  late final StreamController<void> controller;
  final subscriptions = <StreamSubscription<dynamic>>[];

  Future<void> onCancel() async {
    for (final subscription in subscriptions) {
      await subscription.cancel();
    }
  }

  void onListen() {
    for (final stream in streams) {
      subscriptions.add(
        stream.listen(
          (event) {
            controller.add(null);
          },
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  void onPause() {
    for (final subscription in subscriptions) {
      subscription.pause();
    }
  }

  void onResume() {
    for (final subscription in subscriptions) {
      subscription.resume();
    }
  }

  controller = StreamController<void>(
    onCancel: onCancel,
    onListen: onListen,
    onPause: onPause,
    onResume: onResume,
  );

  return controller.stream;
}
```

The returned stream is of type `Stream<void>` so you can't access the event value from it, you need to refer to the original streams reference to get it's current value.

Sample usage in Flutter to merge two cubit streams into a single `StreamBuilder`:

```dart
StreamBuilder<void>(
  stream: combineStreams([
    isLoadingCubit.stream,
    isVisibleCubit.stream,
  ]),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!isVisibleCubit.state) {
      return Container();
    }

    if (isLoadingCubit.state) {
      return MyLoadingSpinner();
    }

    return MyDataWidget();
  },
)
```